# HTML5 cross-browser issue; floating div and list

Tags: internet-explorer, html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; 
    background-color: Green; float:left; margin-right:3em;"></div>
<ol>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome 12 and Firefox 4, this renders a list to the right of the green square. In IE9 the *decimal numerals* are off to the left, overlapping the green square, while the *contents* of the ol is to the right of the green square.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO8Se.png

IE9 with compatibility mode renders the same as Chrome & FF.

- Which browser is "correct"?
- Can you suggest markup that renders like Chrome & FF in all browsers?

Comment: I discovered that `<ol style="display: inline-block;">` "fixes the glitch." But I'm surprised that it's required, and would still appreciate some discussion if someone can explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and firefox are correct although this is quite subjective.

You can try to put a `<div>` around your `<ol>` and float that left too :), or just try to use `inline-block`.

Comment: Why are they correct? because the number should be in front of the text unless otherwise is specified. Also A div floating left should not interfere with the positioning of the <li> elements in any way.

Comment: I thought HTML5 was supposed to make cross-browser easy? :)

Comment: yup, well the W3C has strict rules but browser vendors just always do it "their way".
What can also happen is that something is not clear and up to them to implant or finnally, bugs do happen, but they shouldn't in html.